# How to use crosswalk lite version in Phonegap build?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, crosswalk, crosswalk-runtime

I'm developing an android app through phonegap build which requires crosswalk plugin. My app size is 2.5mb only but when i add crosswalk plugin, App size is 50+ mb and when i run it on phone, it takes 150+ mb disk space which is too much for my audience.

so i was researching and found there is a lite version which reduces half of the size. So in my config file i added following

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" source="npm" version="2.3.0" />
<preference name="xwalkMode" value="lite" />
```

Build is successful but it is still 50+mb.

i guess, lite version is not being enabled. anyone know how to implement lite version of crosswalk plugin?

Many thanks